# Passing arguments to a function while assigning a value to the argument, javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, pass-by-reference

let's say we have variable a = "value1" and I pass it to a function through an argument called "arg"
now inside the function, I'm assigning arg to a value "value2"

my question is :
how passing arguments really work?
will "value2" be assigned to "arg" or variable "a" or both?
does arg get replaced with variable a (during passing)?
and what really confuses me is what gets passed, is it the name of the variable or its value ?
thank's

```
    var a = "value1";

    function myfunc(arg) {        
        arg="value2";
    }

    myfunc(a);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: The question asks about JavaScript though, not Java.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) instead.